# Angular Translate - using an angular expression as the key

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

First I will try to write down what I'm trying to do, then if you guys can't understand or actually need code to fully understand what I want, I will post a code example. 
I'm trying to translate a content using Angular Translate, but using a angular expression as the key. {{ 'key' | translate }} in this case, since I'm pulling information out of a service, then transfering that info into a controller so I can push into the html, I need to know if it's possible to do that.

so like,

{{ '{{product.productDetails}}' | translate }}

So in this case what's coming out of the product.producDetails would be some content, and that content would serve as a key to be translated depending upon the language selected by the person.

Anyways, 
Let me know if someone can help.
Thanks 
Renan

Answer (score 1):

It even simpler than you thought:

```
{{ product.productDetails | translate }}
```

[Here's](http://plnkr.co/edit/TtPHLZOQ1s45qYambV9r?p=preview) working demo

Comment: Thank you Aleksey L, that worked like a charm ;). totally simpler than I thought hehe.

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error.

Instead of

```
{{ '{{product.productDetails}}' | translate }}
```

just use this

```
{{ 'product.productDetails' | translate }}
```

and there should be json object which map the keys with the actual text messages
and provide that json object to translateprovider and give translation name bellow is sample .

**Example:**

```
var englishTranslations = {'productDetails':'please enter product details'}

$translateProvider.translations('en', englishTranslations);

$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
```